# Obtain an ordered list of DOM's focus order

Tags: javascript, html, dom, keyboard, accessibility

I appreciate that the DOM is a dynamic beast, at times. But, I am wondering if there is a simple call I can make to obtain an ordered list of the DOM's focusable elements/nodes at any given time? This would obviously include all nodes with a `tabindex` declaration that wasn't `-1`, as well as any nodes that are focusable by default.

TY.

Comment: There is not an out of the box function, you can of course write your own function to filter all the elements you need. Did you try to do this?

Comment: I haven't tried as yet, as I was waiting to see if there perhaps was an out-of-the-box way to do this (or at least something very closely resembling an out-of-the-box solution). If the answer is that I need to create custom logic, I suppose the obvious solution would be to recursively query the DOM tree, looking for `tab-index` attributes, as well as specific tags known to be focusable by default, then reordering the elements with `tab-index`es based on their numeric values (as it influences the priority order)?

Comment: Yes, this is how to achieve this.

Comment: Cheers. Thanks for responding and ultimately answering my question :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in function to do this, however I do believe the following would work as expected.

As you can see it is not entirely straight forward as you have to account for parent elements having `visibility:hidden` and `display: none` set on them. I also had to add a workaround for `contenteditable` as that is focusable but presents itself as `tabindex="-1"` in JavaScript, even if no `tabindex` is set, which broke the way I was checking things.

What I effectively do is grab all the focusable elements using the CSS selector `focusableItems`.

Then I turn those items into an array, while at the same time removing any with a `tabindex="-1"` and any that are hidden.

Finally we sort the resulting array of items with positive `tabindex` at the start and then all other items in DOM order.

It is a bit rough around the edges but seems to pass all the tests I could think of. Sadly `getComputedStyle` was the only way I could think of to account for `visibility: hidden` on a parent item as that was the hardest scenario to solve.

```js
var focusableItems = 'a[href], area[href], input:not([disabled]), select:not([disabled]), textarea:not([disabled]), button:not([disabled]), [tabindex]:not([disabled]), [contenteditable=true]:not([disabled])';

var items = document.querySelectorAll(focusableItems);


var itemsList=[];
for (var i=0;i<items.length;i++) {
  //don't add items with a negative tabindex. Also because "contenteditable" reveals itself as tabindex="-1" in chrome had to add a little workaround.
  if(items[i].tabIndex != "-1" || (items[i].hasAttribute("contenteditable") && !items[i].hasAttribute("tabIndex"))){
    //warning this is a bit slow on thousands of elements but is needed to pick up "visibility: hidden" and "display: none" correctly.
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(items[i]); 
    //check if the item is visible.
    if(items[i].offsetWidth > 0 && items[i].offsetHeight > 0 && items[i].offsetParent && style.display != "none" && style.visibility != "hidden"){
       itemsList.push(items[i]);
    }
  }
}


//anything with a tabindex needs to be first in the list but also from smallest to largest.
itemsList.sort(function(a, b){
   var aVal = 999999999999999;
   var bVal = 999999999999999;
   if(a.hasAttribute("tabIndex") && parseInt(a.tabIndex) > 0){
      aVal = parseInt(a.tabIndex);
   }
   if(b.hasAttribute("tabIndex") && parseInt(b.tabIndex) > 0){
      bVal = parseInt(b.tabIndex);
   }
   return aVal - bVal
});





console.log(itemsList);
```

```css
.none{
    display:none;
}
.hidden{
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button tabindex="1">focus me first so you can check tab order against console as you go</button>
    <div contenteditable="true" tabindex="0">editable</div>
    <h1>Here is some stuff</h1>
    <p>The <span contenteditable="true" tabindex="2">quick (second tab)</span> brown fox <span contenteditable="true">jumped (editable)</span> over the lazy dog.</p>
    <input name="vis" value="visible"/>
    <input name="dis" disabled value="disabled"/>
    <input name="notabindex" tabindex="-1" value="negative tabindex"/>
    <button tabindex="4">Ok (fourth)</button>
    <button tabindex="3">Cancel (third)</button>
    <p tabindex="0">(This last content is tabbable.)</p>
    <div class="none" tabindex="0">display: none</div>
    <div class="none">
        <div tabindex="0">display: none nested</div>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden" tabindex="0">visibility: hidden</div>
    <div class="hidden">
        <div tabindex="0">visibility: hidden nested</div>
    </div>
    <button>end button - last item</button>
</div>
```